# SQL: Loop through all columns in a database and alter type

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

We have upgraded our database to bigint from int. However we would like the option to migrate back as a last option. At that point we would need to change the database back.

So basically iterate over all tables and colums and if the type == bigint alter to int. So far I have not found a good way to do this.

We support bot postgres sql and sql server. Not sure of this can be done in a unified way or if two versions are required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply generate ALTER statements

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' + TABLE_NAME + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' INT  ' + CASE when IS_NULLABLE = 'NO' THEN 'NOT' END + ' NULL' + char(13) + 'GO'

FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'bigint'
```

Comment: ... and information_schema is standard, though sometimes things like type names vary, so some OR or CASE statements may be required for type-name differences.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in PostgreSQL to do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bigint_to_int() RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE

    m_Record RECORD;

BEGIN

    FOR m_Record IN
    SELECT information_schema.columns.table_name, information_schema.columns.column_name
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE information_schema.columns.data_type = 'bigint'
    AND information_schema.columns.table_schema = 'public'
    LOOP

        EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE ' || QUOTE_IDENT( m_Record.table_name ) || ' ALTER COLUMN ' || QUOTE_IDENT( m_Record.column_name ) || ' TYPE INTEGER;';

    END LOOP;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Then you can just call it using:

```sql
SELECT bigint_to_int();
```

You would have to do the equivalent in SQL Server as well though...